# text-input get hidden on keyboard popup onsen-ui

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, onsen-ui, monaca

I implemented the following but yet can't see what I am typing. I can see the suggestions while typing, but not what I am typing. Can you help me know where am I going wrong.

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
    <div class="center">Sign up</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <div class="formarea" style="margin-top:234px;">
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar width-half" placeholder="First" value="">
      <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar width-half" placeholder="Last" value="" style="border-width-left: 1px">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar width-full" placeholder="Email" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="password" class="text-input--underbar width-full" placeholder="Password" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="lucent">
      <p class="note">Password - 6 characters or more</p>
    </div>

    <div class="vspc form-row">
      <ons-button modifier="large--cta">Sign up</ons-button>
    </div>
  </div>

</ons-page>
```

Comment: I have the same problem only on Android device. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and found and quick and easy to implement solution for it.
At first you have to install

> cordova-plugin-keyboard

Now you are able to register two new event handlers that are called whenever the keyboard appears on screen. The best place to do this is in

> index.js

of your cordova project's www/scripts folder inside the

> onDeviceReady function

Register the two new event handlers:

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);
```

Also inside your index.js file you implement the corresponding event handler functions that will be called:

```
function keyboardHideHandler(e){
    console.log('Goodnight, sweet prince: %O', e);
}
function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    console.log('Hello :), sweet prince: %O',e);
    var ta = document.activeElement;
    console.log('so scroll into view: %O', ta);
    ta.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

As you can see inside the keyboardShowHandler you get the element that actually has focus (that must be a text input field since the keyboard appeared) and use on simple Javascript function to scroll it into view:

```
var ta = document.activeElement;
console.log('so scroll into view: %O', ta);
ta.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Thats it! Every input field thats tapped smoothly scrolls into the visible screen area above the keyboard.

Comment: I used ta.scrollIntoView(false); This sets the text input to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you remove `style="margin-top:234px;` your sign-up form will be visible. Otherwise, you can use [this cordova plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard) to handle the keyboard and scroll to the element you need when it is shown. Something like:

```
ons.softwareKeyboard.on('show', function() {
  // Scroll, focus or whatever you need to do
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i deliberately added a margin-top in to test the issue.
Well i have apps that have been built on onsen and does not show such type of behavior - where the html form overflows but still the keyboard does not hides the text-input.

Comment: without ons-page tag the issue is resolved 
but since ons-page is mandatory to intialise the root page issue prevails.

Comment: @user2977437 have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ons-input type="text" onclick="return scroll_view(this)" float></ons-input>

function scroll_view(view){
  setTimeout(function() {
      delay(view);
  }, 500)
}

function delay(view){
  view.scrollIntoView();
}
```